# Use XML as input variable to an SP

Tags: xml, t-sql

I am getting an XML parameter and now I want to get the data from it and use that data and call to another SP.

Right now I am trying to split up the input xml variable.

```
DECLARE @XML XML Set @XML = '<Products>
                        <product>
                            <id>3</id>
                            <name>Testar 3</name>
                        </product>
                        <product>
                            <id>6</id>
                            <name>Testar 6</name>
                        </product>
                        <product>
                            <id>15</id>
                            <name>Testar 15</name>
                        </product>
                    </Products>'

SELECT      CAST(A.B.query('./product/id/text()') AS VARCHAR(20)) as id,    CAST(A.B.query('./product/name/text()') AS VARCHAR(50)) as name  FROM @XML.nodes('/Products') as A(B)
```

But this only get me 1 row with 2 columns that look like this.

```
ID          Name 
3615        Testar 3Testar 6Testar 15
```

But what I want is this

```
ID          Name
3           Testar 3
6           Testar 6
15          Testar 15
```

What do I need to change to achive that?

Thanks
Magnus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select 
  P.value('id[1]', 'int') as ID,
  P.value('name[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Name
from @XML.nodes('Products/product') as P(P)
```