# How to do Searching and Filtering Data based on Checkboxes in Many to Many Relationship in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

Basically i have 3 tables like this (with many to many relationship);
[image]
And i am querying searching like this;

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[usp_ContactSearch]  
(  
 @PersonName varchar(60)= '',  
 @MobileNo varchar(20)= '',  
 @Nationlity varchar(50)='' ,
 @ContactTypes varchar(max) = ''
)  
AS  
BEGIN  
   
  SELECT DISTINCT c.ContactId, c.PersonName, ct.ContactType, ct.ContactTypeId
  
  FROM Contact c  
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ContactWithContactType cct
  ON c.ContactId = cct.ContactId
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ContactType ct
  ON cct.CountactTypeId = ct.ContactTypeId
  
  WHERE   
   c.PersonName LIKE CASE WHEN @PersonName='' THEN c.PersonName ELSE '%'+@PersonName+'%' END  
  AND   
   c.MobileNo1 LIKE CASE WHEN @MobileNo='' THEN c.MobileNo1 ELSE '%'+@MobileNo+'%' END  
  AND   
   c.Nationality LIKE CASE WHEN @Nationlity='' THEN c.Nationality ELSE '%'+@Nationlity+'%' END  

END
```

So, the result data by default is;
[image]
So, from the Front End, i have **ContactTypes** (which are dynamic i.e comming from contact types table), and the interface looks like this

[image]

Now, whenever user check the **PropertyOwner**(ContactTypeId=1), The data should be filtered and only those contacts should be shown which are belong to **ContactTypeId=1**
Silarly, when i check the second checkbox i.e **Tenant**(ContactTypeId=2). The data should be more filtered and only those contacts will be displayed which belongs to ContactTypeId= 1 and 2. And similarly for 3rd ContactType, the data should be more filtered and so on and so forth. 
So, the problem is **ContactTypes** are dynamic and i don't know how to handle this situation.

Any help regards to the query and performance is much apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This will work...

```
-- This is User Defined Table Type Variable
Declare @MyTypeDataType ContType 
-- You will pass value to this variable from Front End
Insert into @MyTypeDataType values(1),(2),(3);
-- From Front end you will pass the 
-- selected values to "Table Type Variable" and 
-- also to a "Varchar" Variable
Declare @Type as Varchar(20);
SET @Type = '1,2,3';

SELECT X.* FROM 
(
    -- This query will get all persons, 
     -- who have any one Type u want to Search...
    SELECT      C.*,CTT.ContactType, CTT.ContactTypeId FROM Contact C
    INNER JOIN  ContactWithType CT
    ON          C.ContactId = CT.ContactId
    INNER JOIN  ContactType CTT 
    ON          CTT.ContactTypeId = CT.ContactTypeId
    WHERE       @Type LIKE '%' + CAST(  CT.ContactTypeId AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '%'
) X
INNER JOIN 
(
    -- This will count the Record of each Person,
    -- how many time a persons record exists..
    SELECT      C.ContactId, COUNT(C.ContactId) AS Total    
    FROM        Contact C
    INNER JOIN  ContactWithType CT
    ON          C.ContactId = CT.ContactId
    INNER JOIN  ContactType CTT 
    ON          CTT.ContactTypeId = CT.ContactTypeId
    WHERE       @Type LIKE '%' + CAST(  CT.ContactTypeId AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '%'
    GROUP BY    C.ContactId
)Y
ON  X.ContactId = Y.ContactId
-- Filter persons
AND  Y.Total = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @MyTypeDataType)
```

Comment: just alittle bit of modification in ur code, i achieved what i wanted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend to use split function for your query to filter ContactTypes. For example, when in your form someone check Property Owner and Tenant (contactType = 1, 2) or so on, then you can pass it to your stored proc as such

```
@ContactTypes varchar(max) = '1,2'
```

Then you can use one of the split string function that you need to create. You can refer to this excellent article (http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings).
I use the article function **SplitStrings_Moden** for simple string split.

Then you can use it like in your stored proc like this.

```
And ContactType in (select [item] from SplitStrings_Moden(@ContactTypes , ','))
```

As for performance wise, the example given return a table of string column which in your case, you could cast it to int for better for performance. But i guess you might to test it on your dataset if the performance is reasonable without the casting.

Comment: i tried this but this results as OR clause. i mean, it gives me results i.e works like IN clause. what i need is, whenever we check the checkbox, the data should be more filtered

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using xml datatype for this. You can find more information here.

[Use XML as input variable to an SP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233293/use-xml-as-input-variable-to-an-sp)